# Verification channel - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a ".verify" command. I have a special channel for verification, and I want to make the bot delete every message but not embeds and the .verify command.
Can I somehow do it?

.verify's code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def verify(ctx):
    MEMBER = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name= "♰・Member")
    UNVER = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name= "♰・No Verification")
    embed=discord.Embed(title="<:oktagon:926853473251778601> Verification", description="You are now Verified!", color=0xe67e22)
    if ctx.channel.id == 926848096862887976:
      await ctx.author.add_roles(MEMBER)
      await ctx.author.remove_roles(UNVER)
      await ctx.message.delete()
      await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to delete messages if their [`author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author)s are users and the message is not ".verify", or if the author is a bot, but the message doesn't have embeds. You can use [`ctx.author.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.bot) to check if the author is a bot (returns a boolean) and [`ctx.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds) to check if the message has embeds (returns a list of embeds in the message, we check if the number of embeds is 0).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    user = ctx.author #Just a member, can be a bot or a user. The author of the message.
    if user.bot: #Check if the author is a bot.
        if not ctx.embeds: #Check if embeds are not there in the message.
            print("Deleting because it's a message sent by a bot but doesn't have embeds")
            await ctx.delete()
    elif not user.bot: #Check if the author of the message is a user.
        if ctx.content != ".verify": #Check if the message is not exactly ".verify" (the verify message/command sent by the user).
            print("Deleting because it's not .verify")
            await ctx.delete()
```

The `print()` commands are just for your reference and logging. You can delete them if you want better performance. Check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) for a better understanding.